# Lock a prompt to the bottom of the screen

Tags: user-interface, chat, go

all. I'm writing a chat client in Go as a proof-of-concept of a library I'm in the process of writing. It needs to take user input and print incoming messages in the same terminal window. Consider the following.

```
user@debian ~ $ ./client
no session> 192.168.1.100
> Hello, there!
Hi!
> So, did you get that feature working yet?
Nope. I thought you were going to ask on StackOverflow.
>> Yeah, I'm aski
```

If another message arrives while I'm typing, then it should produce the following.

```
user@debian ~ $ ./client
no session> 192.168.1.100
> Hello, there!
Hi!
> So, did you get that feature working yet?
Nope. I thought you were going to ask on StackOverflow.
Or did you want me to?
>> Yeah, I'm aski
```

Is there a way to do this in Go?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've ever used a console application that behaves like that, it probably used a library like ncurses to do that. You wouldn't want to program that yourself because it's quite complex.

For Go I'd recommend [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go). It's easy to pick up and has a well structured [api](http://go.pkgdoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the proper way to do it (not a console developer) but a while back I did a terminal animation in Go that I ran on my Android phone. Accomplished this by clearing the screen, drawing, clearing, etc.

I dont remember what I used to clear the screen but for example I just tried this, `fmt.Print("\033[2J")` and it seems to work. Word of caution here. The support for escape sequences to clear the screen may differ for platform and even the terminal emulator.

But with that in mind, you could maintain a buffer of what the client should look like, when a message is received, clear the screen, and then alter and reprint the buffer.

Comment: The problem with this would be that every time you clear the screen, you would also delete what the user has typed so far.

Comment: That's why you maintain a buffer of what should be on the screen. When a new msg is received, you'd add that to the buffer and draw the text being written below it

Comment: These escape sequences can be obtained by parsing the output of the `terminfo` binary called on the `$TERM` string. But supposedly it's better to just rely on the curses to do the right thing as suggested in another answer.

Comment: indeed, termbox-go looks great